# Can I use useState hook in class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to solve a React problem on testdome.

This is the task:

> The Message component contains an anchor element and a paragraph below the anchor. Rendering of the paragraph should be toggled by clicking on the anchor element using the following logic:

> At the start, the paragraph should not be rendered.
> After a click, the paragraph should be rendered.
> After another click, the paragraph should not be rendered.
> Finish the Message component by implementing this logic.

This is the solution:

```
// React is loaded and is available as React and ReactDOM
// imports should NOT be used
class Message extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
  }
  
  clickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
     visible: !this.state.visible   
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<React.Fragment>
          <a onClick={this.clickHandler} href="#">Want to buy a new car?</a>
         { this.state.visible && <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>}
        </React.Fragment>);
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";
  
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);

console.log("Before click: " + rootElement.innerHTML);
document.querySelector("a").click();
console.log("After click: " + rootElement.innerHTML);
```

I want to do the same with useState Hook. Here is my code:

```
// React is loaded and is available as React and ReactDOM
// imports should NOT be used
class Message extends React.Component {
  
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  }
  
  render() {
    if(show) {
       return (<React.Fragment>
          <a onClick={toggleVisibility} href="#">Want to buy a new car?</a>
          <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>
        </React.Fragment>);
  } else {
     return (<React.Fragment>
          <a onClick={toggleVisibility} href="#">Want to buy a new car?</a>
        </React.Fragment>);
  }
  }
    
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";
  
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);

console.log("Before click: " + rootElement.innerHTML);
document.querySelector("a").click();
console.log("After click: " + rootElement.innerHTML);
```

This is the Output:

```
Run OK, but 3 out of 3 test cases failed.

Line 5: SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (5:8)

  3 | class Message extends React.Component {
  4 |   
> 5 |   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    |         ^
  6 |   
  7 |   const toggleVisibility = () => {
  8 |     setShow(!show);

Your score is 0% :(
```

Why does it not work? is it not allowed to use hooks in class components?
if thats not possible, how can I change the class component into a function component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `useState()` hook in a Class based component. To do so switch to a functional based component.

You can create a functional component as below

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Message = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a onClick={toggleVisibility} href="#">
        Want to buy a new car?
      </a>
      {show && <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use hooks in class components, only for functional components. You could refactor your Message component into a functional component like the following:

```
export const Message = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  }

  if(show) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <a onClick={toggleVisibility} href="#">Want to buy a new car?</a>
          <p>Call +11 22 33 44 now!</p>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
  } else {
     return (
       <React.Fragment>
          <a onClick={toggleVisibility} href="#">Want to buy a new car?</a>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
  }
}
```